# continuous DC voltage across output pin of an IC (DAC output)

Tags: diodes, analog, protection, output, circuit-protection

I would like to ask you one question.

Actually in the automotive there is chance of 20v or 5v continues output come across output of my IC (PGA400)i.e output of DAC.

I would like to know in general how would be the behavior of IC when we feed the output with power supply.

So I need to protect my IC output from this continues analog output. I very glad if you guys could give some inputs to me in designing protection circuitry on output pin.

I can use just a simple zenar with some resistor but I am not allowed to add any series resistance. As far as I know TVS diodes handle transients but not continuous voltages, so I can't use those also. I tryed using opamp buffer with some feedback resistor but it is becoming complex circuit.

I would like to know is there any simple way to handle my IC from this analog voltages.

In the below figure you can see ...

normally 20v not connected but user might connect it to the 20v instead of ECU input.So I need to protect my IC when 20v is connected.

[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: If you can use an op-amp buffer, please justify why a series resistor is disallowed.

Comment: Sorry I am not allowed to use opamp, as it is becoming complex circuit and about the series resistance I can't add because there is a pullup resistor on the end side and it forms a voltage devider.

Comment: Show the circuit if you want decent help.

Comment: Please see the circuit above..I also added a bit clarification on the below..thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What are your specification? The specification are very clear in the automotive space.

Comment: Specifications as in ?.... for IC maximum output current and voltages are  30mA, 7v. output short circuit for IC is +/-10mA.

Comment: Why are you shorting 20V to ground? You could build bootleg op amp with transistors instead.